# Flutter Web: CreateProcessW failed 2

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, android-sdk-2.1, flutter-web

I am not being able to debug my Flutter Web App. There is an error in the debug console and the webpage won't load up in my browser.

**I tried removing spaces and disabling windows firewall but it is still not working.**

I expect the webpage to load up but nothing happens and I am shown this error in my debug console.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYM5H.png)

```
Registering build targets...
Starting initial build...
Serving DevTools at http://127.0.0.1:49831
Starting resource servers...
Serving `web` on http://localhost:49821
CreateProcessW failed 2
Exited (1)
```

Comment: Please paste your code here. Images with code are really unwanted thing on SO

Answer (score 0):

In my case that happened because I have no Chrome browser installed on my PC.
According to [bug details](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/1735) I found that defining `CHROME_EXECUTABLE` environment variable with a full path to your web browser executable solves the problem.